# Joomla 3.0 administration protection remove iframe

Tags: joomla, admin, protected

I have more **joomla** pages, and i must work at the same time on more admin. panels, so i have created a page where i load pages in iframe, but joomla admin. area is protected from *iframe*, know someone how can i deactivate this protection?

If i try to open in iframe:`www.mypage.com/administrator` then i will be redirected to normal page.

I have tried to create new admin template, without any scripts but protection is yet here, i can't found anything with keyword "iframe" or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for the `noframes` behavior, the `com_login` view loads

`JHtml::_('behavior.noframes');`

which ends up calling the `noFrames` function in the `JHtmlBehavior` class `(libraries/joomla/html/behavior.php)`

which loads

```
$js = "window.addEvent('domready', function () {
          if (top == self) {
             document.documentElement.style.display = 'block'; 
          }" . 
          " else {top.location = self.location; }
       });";
```

basically telling the window to change location, so either change how noFrames works or remvoe the `JHtml::_('behavior.noframes')` call

But note that you shouldnt mod core files as they will get overwritten on updates that need to update that file.